# Kivy: pass data to another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, popup, kivy

I`m trying to make a simple GUI with Kivy(1.9) using a popup to change some options from a list and save it to a db, for example. When i call popup(), Python(3.4.5) crash..

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<PopView>:
    title: 'Popup'
    size_hint: (.8, .8)
    Button:
        text: 'Save'
''')

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        b = Button(text='click to open popup')
        b.bind(on_click=self.view_popup())
        return b

    def view_popup(self):
        a=PopView()
        a.data=[1,2,3,4] #e.g.
        a.open()

class PopView(Popup):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = ListProperty()

    def save_data(self):
        #db.query(self.data)
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of things.

First, if you are going to overite `__init__` remember to call `super`
But in this simple case you dont need `__init__`

Then, there is no `on_click` event on `Button`. Use `on_press` or `on_release`

And last but not least: You dont need to call the method in the bind function. Only pass it (without `()`)

So now your example looks like this.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<PopView>:
    title: 'Popup'
    size_hint: (.8, .8)
    Button:
        text: 'Save'
''')

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        b = Button(text='click to open popup')
        b.bind(on_release=self.view_popup)
        return b

    def view_popup(self,*args):
        a = PopView()
        a.data=[1,2,3,4] #e.g.
        a.open()

class PopView(Popup):
    data = ListProperty()

    def save_data(self):
        #db.query(self.data)
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: it's working now but im newbie and I still do not understand why you use *args in view_popup() function. If i declare data outside __init__(), will i have problems with diferent popview objects? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JavierStacul *args just let you pass multiple arguments, without having to specify each one. In this case only the Button is passed, so you might as well do `def view_pop(self,button)`. You can try to `print(args)` and take a look. If you do `**kwargs` you can pass key=val arguments. Try this `def test(**kwargs): print(kwargs)`  and then test(a=1,b=2).. Even if you define `data` inside __init__ or outside, it will be an instance of the respective object. But when you make a new popup, as you do in this case each time, you create a new data also.